# Why do they use "its" in reference to "borrower in the following sentence?

Tags: pronouns

Credit risk has two components.The first is known as default risk, or default probability, which is the probability that a borrower defaults—that is, fails to meet **its** obligation to make full and timely payments of principal and interest, according to the terms of the debt security.

Comment: Assuming the writer was a native speaker, he was presumably thinking of borrowing by entities like ***banks, companies, governments,...*** Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

A borrower can be a non-human actor, like a business or a governmental entity. That is why *its* is being used here.

Answer (score 0):

**Its** refers to **a borrower**. It is the non-gendered singular possessive pronoun. "A borrower" may be a person (who may have a gender) or a business entity (which does not have a gender).

I might have used **their** (as a singular pronoun!) instead, which is less sterile and could apply to either a gender-neutral person or an anthropomorphized business entity.